# Does Doc2vec support multiple languages?And does transvec lib use for Doc2vec model?

Tags: multilingual, doc2vec

I'm new in machine learning. Now I want to calculate similarity between two documents in different languages (ex: a Vietnamese document and an English document).

I know about if we compare multilingual words, we can use `transvec` in `word2vec`. I want to ask if it is possible in `doc2vec`. How can I do to solve this problem with `doc2vec`? (Now I train `doc2vec` by `gensim`)

Answer (score 0):

The `Doc2Vec` model in Gensim is oblivious to languages. It just applies the very-word2vec-like 'Paragraph Vector' algorithm to learn vectors for runs-of-tokens (documents) that are helpful in predicting words, either alone (pure DBOW mode) or in combintion with nearby-word-to-nearby-word info (DM mdoes).

So, whether it'd work on a multilingual corpus, for any particular purpose –such as detecting when two documents in different languages cover similar topics – will depend entirely on how you train the model, and especially the kind of documents and word-to-word correlations it sees in it training set.

While I've not run the experiments, from my understanding of the algorithm, I would expect it to *possibly* work if:

1. Given lots of data that's a meaningful mix of both languages, so that it has a chance to learn that word A in language 1 and word B in language 2 are related to the same topics. (It might be enough to simply have natural bilingual docs, but would probably help to include documents that include within them equivalent text in both languages. It might even be OK if such documents were rather low-quality mechanistic translations, as long as they overall hint properly as to which words related to each other, even if in the original/natural monolingual docs they never appear together.)
2. Is right-sized to *force* the internal neural network to make use of cross-language correlations. (An oversized model – too many dimensions or rare words – would tend to instead learn the two languages without sharing much internal representation – a sort of overfitting.)

A model with only monolingual examples, and oversized, could tend to work great on English-to-English doc comparisons – putting all English docs in one giant region of the vector-space – and also work great on Vietnamese-to-Vietnamese doc comparisions _ putting all Vietnamese documents in an *arbitrarily-different* giant region of the vector-space. But even an English doc and a Vietnamese doc about the same thing could have very different vectors – because nothing in the training data ever hinted those words covered the same things.

Ultimately, though, you'd need to experiment to see how well it would work, and how much you could help it to work, by ensuring it has useful multilingual hints of cross-language topics.

*Update re your Q about `transvec`*:

I wasn't aware of that library; it looks neat, and seems it may be variant of, and possibly better than, the `TranslationMatrix` model in Gensim.

Both `transvec` & Gensim's `TranslationMatrix` are general tools for learning mappings between separate vector spaces, once you provide a set of known correlated anchors.

As such, they could allow an alternative approach to your goal:

1. create one `Doc2Vec` model using only English documents, create a separate `Doc2Vec` model using only Vietnamese documents, and ensure they're both individually sensible – trained on enough data and giving reasonable results in ad hoc or rigorous evaluations.

2 then, using some good 'gold standard' set of English & Vietnamese document pairs that "should" have the same doc-vector – as for example if they are good translations of each other – use `transvec` to learn how to translate one model's vectors (either from the original training set or later inferences) into the other mdoel's space, for direct comparison to the other space's vectors.

As a vague rule of thumb, I believe you'd want to have *many more* anchor-pairs than there are dimensions in the model. (That is: a mere 100 1-to-1 examples is unlikely to be sufficient to learn a good mapping between 2 300-dimensional spaces – there's too much extra slack/variance on each end for fewer examples to communicate – but a thousand or several thousand examples might work well.)

But of course, the real answer will come through experiments on your data, for your goals.

Comment: I try to find information about `translation_matrix` in `gensim`. In my test code, `train_data` has format: 

`[ (['process', 'searching', 'job', 'stressful',], ['quá_trình', 'tìm_kiếm', 'việc_làm', 'căng_thẳng']),`
But I get error: 
`AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'tags'` in line `trans_matrix = model_trans.train(train_data)`

I don't know format `train_data`. How i fix this error and this code?

Comment: You can read docs about the Gensim `TranslationMatrix` mode at https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/translation_matrix.html and see a notebook demonstrating its use at https://github.com/piskvorky/gensim/blob/develop/docs/notebooks/translation_matrix.ipynb - it doesn't work specifically on `Word2Vec` or `Doc2Vec` models, but any set of named vectors (the `KeyedVectors` type in Gensim) whatever their source. But still: it's possible the `transvec` project is a better offering for that generic need.

Comment: With regard to your `AttributeError`, that looks like the sort of error that'd come from a `Doc2Vec` model's `train()`, not a `TranslationMatrix`. `Doc2Vec` needs individual example texts to include the `tags` by which the text's vector(s) should be named. If you're hitting specific errors when trying code for a specific goal, the best chance of receiving hope will be fully detailed questioned focused on the problem, being clear about your intent & the code/data hitting the problem - not really possible to help in these tiny/constrained followup comments about a different question.

Comment: I tried to run test code in https://github.com/piskvorky/gensim/blob/develop/docs/notebooks/translation_matrix.ipynb. with file  `alldata_id_10.txt` but after `infer_vector()` then I called `most_similar()`, I get error:  non-broadcastable output operand with shape (100,) doesn't match the broadcast shape (1,100). `Doc2vec` model has `vector_size = 100`. This is codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/crimson-sky-h2y6kf?file=%2Fmain.py%3A32%2C1

Comment: My target are 
1.calculate similarity between one english document and one vietnamese document
2. find most_similar with a document with result with documents of both languages. I wish you can help me because it's important for my thesis in university.

Comment: If you're having problems with the `translation_matrix.ipynb` notebook, it's possible its demo code has drifted out of working order with other Gensim code or dependencies, but debugging such an issue would require full details of what you're trying, and what error (with full traceback) you're hitting. That'd be pretty separate from your initial question and would be better handled as a new question.

Comment: With regard to your general goals of "similarity between english & vietnamese docs" and "find most-similars among docs of multiple languages from a single starting doc" – what have you tried so far, and to what extent have the results been good or bad? Have you tried training a single model with all the docs, potentially with the suggestion I made in my answer (ensuring some training docs have both languages meaningfully mixed-together in the same documents)?

Comment: Especially in the plain DBOW mode (`dm=0`), it might be enough to simply repeat the same tag (eg `doc001`, etc) for both english & vietnamese language versions of the same document (if you have access to such aligned document pairs, or can create them with translation tools). The translations might not even have to be very good! So if you had no other options, a simple translation-dictionary-replace of every word with its most-direct equivalent in the other language might work reasonably well for creating the alternate-language synthetic doc to match one of your primary training docs.